# Getting error when starting Sidekiq undefined class/module UserMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I don't hv any **UserMailer** and also not defined this to Sidekiq I am not getting what is going wrong.

```
2014-07-15T09:08:34Z 26125 TID-1f0vg2 WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'UserMailer'\n- :receipt\n- - 51\n"], "jid"=>"d298072d05e36665052ac8dd", "enqueued_at"=>1399900307.483016, "error_message"=>"undefined class/module UserMailer", "error_class"=>"ArgumentError", "failed_at"=>1405414127.1232233, "retry_count"=>5, "retried_at"=>1405415314.5643494}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue.After some sequence of restarts (app then sidekiq then redis, or redis then app then sidekiq or redis then app then sidekiq ?) It may work perfectly.

Comment: For me, I don't have redis in the app so no need to restart that. But this issue has been automatically gone when I restarted sidekiq 3-4 times.